# Touchmove with Phonegap

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, cordova

I'm really struggling on an Android app in Phonegap and JQuery.

All I want to do is bind a touchmove to an element and then check the X and Y coordinates as I move my finger (a drag, basically)

```
$('#someElm').bind('touchmove',function(event){
        //Code here..!
});
```

The touchmove fires when I touch the screen, but then I don't really know what the objects of the event are - I've tried event.screenX, event.pageX, but the don't work.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here the reference for mobile safari (android is basically the same):

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/HandlingEvents/HandlingEvents.html

what you want is:

```
var x = event.touches[0].pageX;
var y = event.touches[0].pageY;
```

If you are running on android you also need to cancel the touchmove event to get new ones while touching. Don't ask me why...

Comment: That sort of works thanks, but it doesn't seem to get the individual positions as I drag my finger in the x directions.

It only seems to give me the start position an end position.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have any more code; I've simply added your section into the touchmove event.

I'm writing the x to the screen to see what the position is.

I was expecting it to update the coordinates as I move my finger, but it simply gives me the start x with I touch the screen, and the final x when I release - nothing in between.

Comment: is the number updating on this slider for you when you move it? http://m-gwt.com/showcase/#SliderPlace:null

Comment: Regarding Android's touchmove bug http://uihacker.blogspot.com.es/2011/01/android-touchmove-event-bug.html